# Cannot test callbacks with mockk: invoke(any())) was not called

Tags: kotlin, mocking, mockk

Given

```
typealias MyCallback = (s: String) -> Unit

object Hello {
    fun main() {
        blah { print(it) }
    }
    fun blah(cb: MyCallback) {
        cb.invoke("hi")
    }
}
```

Or

```
interface MyCallback {
    fun invoke (s: String) {}
}

object Hello {
    fun main() {
        blah(object : MyCallback {
            override fun invoke(s: String) {
                print(s)
            }
        })
    }
    fun blah(cb: MyCallback) {
        cb.invoke("hi")
    }
}
```

With both I get the above error (`Verification failed: call 1 of 1: MyCallback(#2).invoke(any())) was not called`) when doing

```
    @Test
    fun testInvoke() {
        val mock = mockk<Hello>(relaxed = true)
        val cb = mockk<MyCallback>()
        mock.blah(cb)
        verify { cb.invoke(any()) }
    }
```

how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me. The `Hello` object doesn't need to be mocked since it is the class being tested. By mocking it, the test was only recording invocations of `blah()` rather than actually executing them.

Using `spyk` rather than `mockk` allows the `MyCallback` type to be constructed allowing the `invoke()` function to be defined. So maybe that's more of a workaround than an explanation of why mockk doesn't seem to retain that type info.

```
typealias MyCallback = (s: String) -> Unit

object Hello {
    fun main() {
        blah { print(it) }
    }
    fun blah(cb: MyCallback) {
        cb.invoke("hi")
    }
}

class MockKTest {

    @Test
    fun testInvoke() {
        val mock = spyk<Hello>()
        val cb = mockk<MyCallback>(relaxed = true)
        mock.blah(cb) // or just do Hello.blah(cb)
        verify { cb.invoke(any()) }
    }
}
```

Comment: You put me on the right path. Leaving `mockk` for the callback and doing _either_ `Hello.blah` (static method invocation) _or_ `spyk<Hello>()` makes it pass. Again, the callback does not need to be a spy, and simply making it a spy _does not_ fix the issue.

Comment: there is also `mockkObject(Hello)` as another option